# Use of Json Web Tokens with OAuth 2

Tags: security, oauth-2.0

I am trying to build an authorization and authentication system with OAuth 2 and I am having some question regarding the generation of the different strings.

- `client_id`: in order to generate the `client_id`, I use an [`ObjectId`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) coming from `mongoDB`, it is of this form: `507f1f77bcf86cd799439011`
- `client_secret`: I use a random generated string (48 chars) created by the [`crypto`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randombytes_size_callback) module of NodeJS
- `access_token`: For the moment, I use a JWT Token because I like the principle of being able to hold information through that token, and being able to access resources without querying the authentication server at each request (stateless architecture).
- `refresh_token`: I would also like to use a JWT for this kind of token.

The question is: Is it a bad practice to use a JWT Token in OAuth 2? If this is a bad practice why? Is their something bad with my `client_id` and `client_secret` generation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JWT for tokens is OK (e.g. Microsoft Azure uses tokens in JWT form), there is just one thing to be aware of. If you decide to implement the [revocation endpoint](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7009), you will either have to set the lifetime of the tokens to a short time (so they are not used too long after being revoked) or to check their validity at the [introspection endpoint](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7662) of the OAuth2 server.

With the `client_id`, if the `ObjectId` is a record identifier in MongoDb, I would use a non-DB-generated value for that. With generated values, you may run into problems if you get a requirement to use a custom value as a `client_id`. This is not a strong argument, but I think it's worth considering.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Regarding the revocation, I was planning to handle this with 1h tokens, 24h refresh tokens and a black list of access_tokens identifiers replicated on each resource server. I was also planning to do a blacklist on the client_id level.